# $f_n ^{'}$ is uniformly convergent but the seq $f_n$ is not uniformly convergent.

Tags: real-analysis, uniform-convergence

Let $f_n(x) = n + x/n , x \in \mathbb R$. Then the seq $f_n ^{'}$ is uniformly convergent but the seq $f_n$ is not uniformly convergent.

We see that $f_n ^{'} = 1/n$ which is trivially uniformly convergent.But how to prove that $f_n$ is not uniformly convergent.

Comment: $(f_n)$ isn't even pointwise convergent.

Comment: yeah thats true.... so I am thinking why such  a problem is given?

Comment: I think the following result is of interest here: Let $(f_n)$ be a sequence of differentiable functions on the bounded interval $(a,b)$ such that $(f_n')$ converges uniformly on $(a,b)$. If there is $c\in(a,b)$ with $(f_n(c))$ convergent, then $(f_n)$ converges uniformly on $(a,b)$ and $\lim f_n'=(\lim f_n)'$.

Answer (score 1):

If $f_n$ is uniformly convergent then it is also u.c. on compact subsets (closed intervals). On a compact subset you easily prove the estimate
$
|f_n(x)-f_m(x)|\ge c_0 |n-m|
$
for sufficiently large m, n; where $c_0$ is a constant. Now you get easily a contradiction because $(n)$ is not a Cauchy sequence.
You should have no difficulty in working out the details. Good luck!